# Opengl Translation on Model Matrix malforms result

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl

I am trying to build a model matrix where I apply some common transformations like scaling, rotation and translation. I was following a tutorial here: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/05/22/opengl-101-matrices-projection-view-model/. I know that matrixes are not commutative so I think I paid attention to get the correct order of transformations.

But when I try to translate my model it gets stretched into the corresponding axis instead of translating.
Here is how it looks:

[image]

I would appreciate any help. :)

Vertex shader

```java
# version 330

in vec3 in_pos;
in vec3 in_col;
in vec3 in_norm;

// uniform wie eine konstante, kann einmal per frame geaender werden und gillt fuer alle vertices
uniform mat4 mvp; // mat4 = 4x4 Matrix

// out stream to fragment shader
out vec4 frag_pos;
out vec4 frag_col;
out vec4 frag_norm;

// column major
void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(in_pos, 1.0);
    frag_pos = vec4(in_pos,1.0);
    // transparent frag_col = vec4(in_col,0.5);
    frag_col = vec4(in_col,1);
    frag_norm = vec4(in_norm,1.0);
}
```

Java transformations

```
float aspectRatio = (float) HEIGHT /(float)WIDTH;

float[][] rotX = new float[][] {
        {1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f},
        {0.0f,(float)Math.cos(thetaX),(float)-Math.sin(thetaX),0.0f},
        {0.0f,(float)Math.sin(thetaX),(float)Math.cos(thetaX),0.0f},
        {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f}
};

float[][] rotY = new float[][] {
        {(float)Math.cos(thetaY),0.0f,(float)Math.sin(thetaY),0.0f},
        {0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f},
        {(float)-Math.sin(thetaY),0.0f,(float)Math.cos(thetaY),0.0f},
        {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f}
};

float[][] rotZ = new float[][] {
        {(float)Math.cos(thetaZ),(float)-Math.sin(thetaZ),0.0f,0.0f},
        {(float)Math.sin(thetaZ),(float)Math.cos(thetaZ),0.0f,0.0f},
        {0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f},
        {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f}
};

float[][] translation = new float[][] {
        {1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,transX},
        {0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,transY},
        {0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,transZ},
        {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f}
};

float[][] scaleMatrix = new float[][] {
        {scale,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f},
        {0.0f,scale,0.0f,0.0f},
        {0.0f,0.0f,scale,0.0f},
        {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f}
};

float[][] aspect = new float[][] {
        {aspectRatio,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f},
        {0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f},
        {0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f},
        {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f}
};

float[][] rotationMatrix = Matrix.matMult(rotZ,Matrix.matMult(rotY,rotX));
float[][] matrix = Matrix.matMult(translation,Matrix.matMult(rotationMatrix,scaleMatrix));

float[] model = Matrix.matrixToFloatVector(Matrix.matMult(matrix,aspect));

FloatBuffer fb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
fb.put(model);

fb.flip();  // Reset pointer
// "upload" to graphics card
glUniformMatrix4fv(uLocMVP, false, fb);
```

Comment: You've to transpose the matrix. `glUniformMatrix4fv(uLocMVP, true, fb)`

Comment: Yes indeed that worked, thank you, if you feel like it can you maybe explain to me why it works after transposing?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Is it because opengl works with column majors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [The OpenGL Shading Language 4.6, 5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf#page=112&zoom=100,0,918), page 110:

> To initialize a matrix by specifying vectors or scalars, the components are assigned to the matrix elements in column-major order.
>
> ```c
> mat4(float, float, float, float,  // first column
>      float, float, float, float,  // second column
>      float, float, float, float,  // third column
>      float, float, float, float); // fourth column
> ```

This means you have to transpose the matrix before setting the uniform variable of type `mat4`.

This can be done automatically by setting the 3rd parameter of [`glUniformMatrix4fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) `true`:

```java
glUniformMatrix4fv(uLocMVP, true, fb)
```

---

Instead you can transpose the initialization and swap the matrix multiplications (`Matrix.matMult`), too.